# Should I care about File#separator for Path#resolve(String)

Tags: java, path, nio, separator

I'm writing a method copies files from HDFS to local disk.

```
String pathString = ".../.../..."; slash-separated HDFS path string
Path directory = ...;

Path target = directory.resolve(pathString);
```

Now should I replace all slashes with `File#separator` with `pathString`?

In other words,

Can I do following even with Windows?

```java
Path base = Path.get(a, b);
String pathname = "c/d";
Path target = base.resolve(pathname); // Will work as a\b\c\d?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File#separator` is not necessary if you want to keep your path logic platform-agnostic. An easier way to do it is to build the child path with [`Paths.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) and resolve that. E.g.,:

```java
Path path = Paths.get("a", "b", "c");
Path directory = ...;

Path target = directory.resolve(path);
```

Comment: I don't think you're being clear here. Yes, what you showed works. The slashes __also__ work. Even on windows.

Comment: I've heard that's the case and I trust it to be true (I don't personally develop for Windows these days), though I haven't seen that formally documented anywhere either. That said, if the goal is to have platform-agnostic logic, let's keep in mind that are more cases than just Windows with NTFS or POSIX-style filesystems.

Comment: @rzwitserloot You mean the `resolve` method takes care of file separator?

Comment: Yes, and so does `Paths.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer.

```java
// event with Windows
final Path directory = Paths.get("a", "b");
final String pathname = "c/d";
final Path resolved = directory.resolve(pathname);
log.debug("resolved: {}", resolved.toAbsolutePath());
```

I got `.:\...\a\b\c\d`.